# VBA JSON - Getting an empty value

Tags: json, vba, excel

I have a sample JSON file here.

```
{
    "tournaments": [{
        "id": "sr:tournament:30",
        "name": "Champions League",
        "sport": {
            "id": "sr:sport:6",
            "name": "Handball"
        },
        "category": {
            "id": "sr:category:73",
            "name": "International"
        },
        "current_season": {
            "id": "sr:season:41860",
            "name": "Champions League 17\/18",
            "start_date": "2017-09-02",
            "end_date": "2018-05-28",
            "year": "17\/18"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "sr:tournament:57",
        "name": "DHB Pokal",
        "sport": {
            "id": "sr:sport:6",
            "name": "Handball"
        },
        "category": {
            "id": "sr:category:53",
            "name": "Germany",
            "country_code": "DEU"
        },
        "current_season": {
            "id": "sr:season:41782",
            "name": "DHB Pokal 17\/18",
            "start_date": "2017-08-18",
            "end_date": "2018-05-31",
            "year": "17\/18"
        }
    }]
}
```

I parsed the file using [This](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).
I want to get all the data in tournaments.
What is the best way to get the it?

can it be done using arrays and not with strings? `JSons(1)(1)` and not `JSons(1)("id")` ?

here's my code

```
Set JSons = jsonObj("tournaments")

For Each json In JSons

For i = 1 To json.Count
    Cells(a, b) = json(1)
    b = b + 1

Next

a = a + 1
b = 1

Next
```

`json(1)` is returning an empty value but when I do this `JSons(1)("id")` I'm getting the value.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing question. I want to get the value of id using json(1) and not json("id") . its getting an empty value when I do this json(1). and my json is a tournament dictionary

Comment: Ok. First you need to understand your Jsons is an object set; json is an object. Your json(1) is a wrong syntax , you need to pass the "key" value inside the brackets

Comment: Secondly, you can't do json.Count of an ojbect. Either you use "For Each json In JSons" or "For i = 1 To Jsons.Count" . you can only count the collection or a set

Comment: but @Nexus , am I passing it already in `For each json in JSons`?
So this is my interpretation, JSons is a list of Tournaments, for each tournament(json), I want to output the value id so I use json(1) because its in the firs item. then iterate it to get all the values in tournament.

Comment: How do you think I should tackle this? without using "id" or any strings rather than integer?

Comment: Then you need to Set json to be a collection or a Set as well

Comment: probably easier to query the JSON with Power Query - Data tab > New Query > From File > From JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get JSON data into arrays as shown in the example code below. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ' Put sourse JSON string to "\source.json" file, and save as ANSI or Unicode

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    sJSONString = ReadTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\source.json", -2)
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    vJSON = vJSON("tournaments")
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath As String, lFormat As Long) As String
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi Sir Omegastripes. I just want to thank you for helping to sort this thing. your reply actually helped me a lot. Thanks Sir!

Comment: Sir I have a question, Is it possible to put a group of data  into one cell? example I have a nested JSON file. then the last one is a group of data in a time series. Can I put all of it in once cells by concatinating them? Thank you Sir.

Comment: @remoel please add to the question a screenshot of a worksheet showing expected output.

Comment: so let's say I have this JSON file 
[
  {
    "match_id": 3455216870,
    "radiant_gold_adv": [
      0,
      -41,
      -56,
      -535,
      -447,
      -639
    ]
  }
]

I want the rad_gold_adv to stay the same.
This is my desired output.
match_id       | rad_gold_adv
3455216870  | [0,-31,-41,56...]

The thing is that group of data are being input on each cell.

Comment: @remoel then you need just loop through each root array element: get the array from `radiant_gold_adv`, convert it into string with `Join()`, and put result string back to array element.

Comment: ohh I forgot that. mmm where do you think I should put that in the above code? or I guess I make another code right? Thank you again Sir.

Comment: @remoel Seems that is another issue, comments isn't the right place for extended discussion. Edit the question or raise another one. Share JSON sample, desired output from these comments and the code you have tried.

Comment: ahh yes my bad sir. sorry i forgot about it. but still, thank you again sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I'm getting the values with these.

```
Set JSons = jsonObj("tournaments")

For Each tournament In JSons
    i=1
    For each json in tournament
        Cells(a, b) = jsons(i)(json)
        b = b + 1
    Next
a = a + 1
b = 1

Next
```

Comment: I did that and its still fetching an empty value. D:

Comment: I got the value by these method.